# consistent hashing on Multiple machines

Tags: hash, consistent-hashing

I've read the article: http://n00tc0d3r.blogspot.com/  about the idea for consistent hashing, but I'm confused about the method on multiple machines.

The basic process is:

Insert

1. Hash an input long url into a single integer;
2. Locate a server on the ring and store the key--longUrl on the server;
3. Compute the shorten url using base conversion (from 10-base to 62-base) and return it to the user.(***How does this step work? In a single machine, there is a auto-increased id to calculate for shorten url, but what is the value to calculate for shorten url on multiple machines? There is no auto-increased id***.)

Retrieve

1. Convert the shorten url back to the key using base conversion (from 62-base to 10-base);
2. Locate the server containing that key and return the longUrl. (***And how can we locate the server containing the key?***)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any clear answer on that page for how the author intended it.  I think this is basically an exercise for the reader.  Here's some ideas:

1. Implement it as described, with hash-table style collision resolution.  That is, when creating the URL, if it already matches something, deal with that in some way.  Rehashing or arithmetic transformation (eg, add 1) are both possibilities.  This means, naively, a theoretical worst case of having to hit a server n times trying to find an available key.

There's a lot of ways to take that basic idea and smarten it, eg, just search for another available key on the same server, eg, by rehashing iteratively until you find one that's on the server.

2. Allow servers to talk to each other, and coordinate on the autoincrement id.
3. This is probably not a great solution, but it might work well in some situations: give each server (or set of servers) separate namespace, eg, the first 16 bits selects a server.  On creation, randomly choose one.  Then you just need to figure out how you want that namespace to map.  The namespaces only really matter for who is allowed to create what IDs, so if you want to add nodes or rebalance later, it is no big deal.

Let me know if you want more elaboration.  I think there's a lot of ways that this one could go.  It is annoying that the author didn't elaborate on this point; my experience with these sorts of algorithms is that collision resolution and similar problems tend to be at the very heart of a practical implementation of a distributed system.